# Create a Numpy array from parts of other arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**EDIT**

So I just understand now that Python and Numpy just don't do polymorphism very well. Given the same data, it has to be put into the right form before most functions can use it. So expecting Python to be able to 'one-line' something is beyond its capabilities.

Just for comparison, MATLAB doesn't do polymorphism very well either but it's much less noticeable as by default it keeps all numeric data as a 2D array so the majority of functions will work with the majority of data - making it soooo much easier

**EDIT**

I'm pretty new to Python and struggling to create new arrays out of existing arrays:

In MATLAB the following works to create a column vector from other column vectors:

a = [b(5:6); c(N:M); d(1:P); e(Q)]

with a lot of computational flexibility (Q could be a vector for example).

In Python, I can't find a nice command to add multiple 1D NumPy arrays together and it seems to have lots of issues with single values as it changes them from NumPy arrays to some other format, WHY?!

Can anyone give me a single line of code to carry out the above? It'd be great to see - so far all I've got is lines and lines of checking for the indexing variables (N, M, P, Q) and soooo many np.array(..)'s everywhere to try and keep things the same data type.

I've tried np.append but that doesn't work for multiple vectors (I could nest them but that seems very ugly, esp if I need to add many arrays) and np.concatenate complains that something is 0-dimensional, I don't understand that at all.

Comment: In matlab everything is 2d.  numpy arrays can be 0d (scalar), 1d, 20d.  That `[;]` notation is a form of concatenate.  `hstack` is a version of `concatenate` that easily joins 1d and 0d/scalars

Comment: np.append is just np.concatenate for 2 arguments, with a bit shape tweaking.  Look at its code if you don't understand what.

Comment: Please, can you give examples - I've tried a lot of these and they don't seem to work. Good chance I'm getting the syntax incorrect, as I can't find an example that does all the things I want in the same example.

Answer (score 2):

`concatenate` has no problems with a bunch of 1d array:

```
In [52]: np.concatenate([np.array([1,2,3]), np.ones((2,)), np.array([1])])
Out[52]: array([1., 2., 3., 1., 1., 1.])
```

If one argument is scalar:

```
In [53]: np.concatenate([np.array([1,2,3]), np.ones((2,)), 1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-53-51b00c09f677>", line 1, in <module>
    np.concatenate([np.array([1,2,3]), np.ones((2,)), 1])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 2 has 0 dimension(s)
```

It make a array from the last

```
In [57]: np.array(1)
Out[57]: array(1)
```

but that's a 0d array.  In MATLAB that would be 2d - everything is 2d, there's not true scalars.  Remember, `numpy` works in python, which has scalars and lists.  MATLAB is matrices all the way down ...

Also numpy arrays can be 0d or 1d.  There's no artificial 2d lower bound.  It's a general array language, not just matrices.  In MATLAB even 3d is a tweak on the original 2d.

`hstack` adds a tweak to make sure all arguments are at least 1d:

```
In [54]: np.hstack([np.array([1,2,3]), np.ones((2,)), 1])
Out[54]: array([1., 2., 3., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Even in MATLAB/Octave mismatched dimensions give problems:

```
>> a = [3:5; [1,2,3]]
a =    
   3   4   5
   1   2   3

>> a = [3:5; [1,2,3]; 4]
error: vertical dimensions mismatch (2x3 vs 1x1)

>> a = [3:5; [1,2,3,4]]
error: vertical dimensions mismatch (1x3 vs 1x4)
>> a = [3:5, [1,2,3,4]]
a =    
   3   4   5   1   2   3   4

>> a = [3:5, [1,2,3,4],5]
a =
   3   4   5   1   2   3   4   5
```

Comment: Thanks for the break down, just on the last point - yeah, garbage in garbage out, true for any language. 
So, to re-iterate my original question, Can you write the example in one line of Python?

Take multiple bits of already existing arrays, some of which are single values, and create a new array? I think I need a direct example to be able to get the syntax right.

Your example only created an array from arrays that you've created in the line, you haven't done any indexing of existing arrays or single value indexes

Comment: You didn't provide a [mcve].  I tried to illustrate the core of the problem.  I don't think the indexing is the issue.

Comment: OK:
a = [b[5:6], d[1:P], e[Q]] creates errors and wont create a numpy array - what syntax will? First if  P = 2 and Q = 1, then if P = 0 and Q = the numbers 1 to 3?

Comment: If you didn't get a SyntaxError, then syntax isn't your problem.

Comment: [x] creates something different to x, mathematically it's the same data, the only difference is syntax

Answer (score 0):

you would want to look on
np.concatenate
which take sequence of arrays and axis to concatnate them on

Comment: tried concatenate it can't deal with single values being added, something about 0D issues

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a sequence of arrays as scalars. You want to join them into a single sequence, but when you try to join them, the scalars cause trouble.

You should first convert all the scalars into singleton arrays. Then join them. Something like:

```py
foo = [[1, 2, 3], 5, [6, 7], 8]
foo2 = [np.array(item) if isinstance(item, list) else np.array([item]) for item in foo]
np.concatenate(foo)
```